# CUDA transpose kernel fails randomly

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, transpose, gpu-shared-memory

I am trying to transpose a matrix. It works as expected for some values and starts crashing with bigger ones or even between executions of the program.

What I am trying to make is to split the matrix in n by n blocks, each one launches `SEGMENT_SIZE` threads and each thread processes a column of its block. For now I am assuming that `MATRIX_SIZE` is divisible by `SEGMENT_SIZE`.

Invocation and parameters:

```
#define MATRIX_SIZE 64
#define SEGMENT_SIZE 32

int n_block = (MATRIX_SIZE % SEGMENT_SIZE) ? MATRIX_SIZE / SEGMENT_SIZE + 1 : MATRIX_SIZE / SEGMENT_SIZE;

dim3 blocksPerGrid(n_block, n_block);
dim3 threadsPerBlock(SEGMENT_SIZE);
transposeMatrix<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock, threadsPerBlock.x * threadsPerBlock.x * sizeof(float)>>>(d_data, MATRIX_SIZE);
```

Kernel:

```
__global__ void transposeMatrix(float *d_data, int mat_dim)
{
    //  Array in Shared Memory
    extern __shared__ float sdata[];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < blockDim.x; i++)
    {

        sdata[blockDim.x * i + threadIdx.x] = d_data[(i + blockIdx.y * blockDim.x) * mat_dim + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x)];
    }
    __syncthreads();

    for (int i = 0; i < blockDim.x; i++)
    {
        d_data[(i + blockIdx.y * blockDim.x) + (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) * mat_dim] = sdata[threadIdx.x + i * blockDim.x];
    }
}
```

For `MATRIX_SIZE` 64 and `SEGMENT_SIZE` 32 works as expected and never fails, but for bigger values of `MATRIX_SIZE` (like 480) it starts behaving unexpectedly and on some executions the resulting matrix is not correct.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Ok, I understand. I have gone for the first approach and everything is working consistently. However, I didnt understand your second solution, could you explain it a bit deeper?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doubtful that an in-place transpose could work the way you have it designed here. `__syncthreads()` does not synchronize the entire grid, only each block. Therefore, in a larger test case, you will have some threadblocks writing their output over input data that has not yet been read in by some other threadblock.

Two options would be to:

1. make the output matrix different than the input matrix,

or:

2. assign each block to handle the data tile on each side of the diagonal. You would first load both tiles into shared memory, then do __syncthreads(), then write out both tiles. This only works for square arrays, but your problem has square arrays in view.

(A third option not covered here would be to replace your usage of `__syncthreads()` with an appropriate [cooperative kernels grid-wide sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53777190/inter-block-synchronization-in-cuda/53781804#53781804).)

Here is a worked example demonstrating both ideas:

```
$ cat t24.cu
#include <iostream>

__global__ void transposeMatrix(float *o_data, float *i_data,  int mat_dim)
{
    //  Array in Shared Memory
    extern __shared__ float sdata[];

    for (int i = 0; i < blockDim.x; i++)
    {

        sdata[blockDim.x * i + threadIdx.x] = i_data[(i + blockIdx.y * blockDim.x) * mat_dim + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x)];
    }
    __syncthreads();

    for (int i = 0; i < blockDim.x; i++)
    {
        o_data[(i + blockIdx.y * blockDim.x) + (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) * mat_dim] = sdata[threadIdx.x + i * blockDim.x];
    }
}

__global__ void transposeMatrix_ip(float *d_data,  int mat_dim)
{
    //  Array in Shared Memory
    extern __shared__ float sdata[];
    if (blockIdx.x >= blockIdx.y){  // only need blocks on or "above" the diagonal
      for (int i = 0; i < blockDim.x; i++)
      {

        sdata[blockDim.x * i + threadIdx.x] = d_data[(i + blockIdx.y * blockDim.x) * mat_dim + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x)];
        if (blockIdx.x != blockIdx.y) sdata[(blockDim.x*blockDim.x)+blockDim.x * i + threadIdx.x] = d_data[(i + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) * mat_dim + (blockDim.x * blockIdx.y + threadIdx.x)];
      }
      __syncthreads();

      for (int i = 0; i < blockDim.x; i++)
      {
        d_data[(i + blockIdx.y * blockDim.x) + (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) * mat_dim] = sdata[threadIdx.x + i * blockDim.x];
        if (blockIdx.x != blockIdx.y) d_data[(i + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) + (threadIdx.x + blockIdx.y * blockDim.x) * mat_dim] = sdata[(blockDim.x*blockDim.x)+ threadIdx.x + i * blockDim.x];
      }
    }
}

int main(){

#define MATRIX_SIZE 4000
#define SEGMENT_SIZE 32

  int n_block = (MATRIX_SIZE % SEGMENT_SIZE) ? MATRIX_SIZE / SEGMENT_SIZE + 1 : MATRIX_SIZE / SEGMENT_SIZE;
  float *d_idata, *d_odata, *h_idata, *h_odata;
  cudaMalloc(&d_idata, MATRIX_SIZE*MATRIX_SIZE*sizeof(float));
  cudaMalloc(&d_odata, MATRIX_SIZE*MATRIX_SIZE*sizeof(float));
  h_idata = new float[MATRIX_SIZE*MATRIX_SIZE];
  h_odata = new float[MATRIX_SIZE*MATRIX_SIZE];
  int q = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
      h_idata[i*MATRIX_SIZE+j] = q++;
  cudaMemcpy(d_idata, h_idata, MATRIX_SIZE*MATRIX_SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
  dim3 blocksPerGrid(n_block, n_block);
  dim3 threadsPerBlock(SEGMENT_SIZE);
  transposeMatrix<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock, threadsPerBlock.x * threadsPerBlock.x * sizeof(float)>>>(d_odata, d_idata, MATRIX_SIZE);
  cudaMemcpy(h_odata, d_odata, MATRIX_SIZE*MATRIX_SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  q = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
      if (h_odata[j*MATRIX_SIZE+i] != q++) {std::cout << "1mismatch at: " << i << "," << j << " was: " << h_odata[j*MATRIX_SIZE+i] << " should be: " << q-1 << std::endl; break; break;}

  transposeMatrix_ip<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock, 2*threadsPerBlock.x * threadsPerBlock.x * sizeof(float)>>>(d_idata, MATRIX_SIZE);
  cudaMemcpy(h_odata, d_idata, MATRIX_SIZE*MATRIX_SIZE*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
  q = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < MATRIX_SIZE; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < MATRIX_SIZE; j++)
      if (h_odata[j*MATRIX_SIZE+i] != q++) {std::cout << "2mismatch at: " << i << "," << j << " was: " << h_odata[j*MATRIX_SIZE+i] << " should be: " << q-1 << std::endl; break; break;}

}
$ nvcc -o t24 t24.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t24
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

this in-place approach has each block handling 2 tiles.  Therefore we only need blocks on or on one side of the diagonal to act.  Those blocks each load 2 tiles into shared memory, and then write out those two tiles. Therefore twice as much shared mem per block is needed.  For the blocks on the diagonal (`blockIdx.x == blockIdx.y`) we only need one tile operation per block not two.

Also note that the matrix size (4000) here is chosen carefully to avoid overflowing the integer-storage capacity of a `float` quantity.  If you make this test case much larger, it will probably fail due to the larger integers involved in the test case, not because the method is flawed.